# SQL search for occurrences of transaction types within multiple date ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID INT,
    UserName VARCHAR(100)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE Trans
(
    UserID INT,
    TransID INT,
    TransTypeID INT,
    TransDate DATETIME,
    TransAmount DECIMAL(15,2)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE TransType
(
    TransTypeID INT,
    TransTypeName VARCHAR(10)
)
```

Lets say for simplicity there are only 2 entries in TransType table:

1. Income
2. Expense

I'm looking to find out if 3 or more transactions of type Income AND 3 or more transactions of type Expense occurred within a particular time period over a date range for a particular user.

So for example, my search could have the following variables:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018-06-30'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2019-09-30'
DECLARE @SearchPeriodMonths INT = 6
```

My current solution searches in blocks of 6 months (as defined by @SearchPeriodMonths) from @StartDate to @EndDate and if 3 or more transactions of Income and Expense exist, then this would need to be returned in a table.  This solution is not very efficient and involves using a cursor.  I'm hoping there is a better way of going about it.

```
CREATE TABLE #Results
(
    UserID int,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME,
    Message VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @UserID INT

DECLARE crUser CURSOR FOR
SELECT UserID
FROM Users

OPEN crUser
FETCH NEXT FROM crUser INTO @UserID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateCount TABLE(UserID INT, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME, IncomeCount INT, ExpenseCount INT)

    WHILE(@StartDate < @EndDate)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate)
        INSERT INTO @DateCount
        SELECT
            @UserID AS UserID,
            @StartDate AS StartDate,
            DATEADD(MONTH, @SearchPeriodMonths, @StartDate) AS EndDate, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Trans WHERE TransTypeID = 1 AND UserID = @UserID 
                AND TransDate BETWEEN @StartDate and DATEADD(MONTH, @SearchPeriodMonths, @StartDate) 
                AS IncomeCount,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Trans WHERE TransTypeID = 2 AND UserID = @UserID 
                AND TransDate BETWEEN @StartDate and DATEADD(MONTH, @SearchPeriodMonths, @StartDate) 
                AS ExpenseCount
    END

    INSERT INTO #Results
    SELECT
      @UserID AS UserID,
      MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
      MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
      '3 or more Income and Expense transaction types occur in a 6 month period between ' 
        + convert(varchar, min(StartDate), 106) + ' and ' 
        + convert(varchar, max(EndDate), 106) AS WarningMessage
    FROM @DateCount
    WHERE IncomeCount > 2 AND ExpenseCount > 2

    FETCH NEXT FROM crUser INTO @UserID
END
CLOSE crUser
DEALLOCATE crUser

-- Output query
SELECT *
FROM #Results

END
```

I am restricted to doing this in SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there a more efficient way to do this which doesn't involve using a cursor?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to find out if 3 or more transactions of type Income AND 3 or more transactions of type Expense occurred within a particular time period over a date range for a particular user.

Use aggregation!

```
select userid
from trans
where transdate between @startdate and dateadd(month, @SearchPeriodMonths, @StartDate)
group by userid
having sum(case when transtypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) >= 3 and
       sum(case when transtypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) >= 3;
```